# VBA advice on form edit functionality

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an excel sheet with a VBA data entry forms. One of the requirements is protecting the sheet from editing after data entry. I added password protection for the sheets and the VBA code. However, on user level mistakes can happen. Therefore, I am looking to create an additional correction form, which allows the user to edit a specific row of data without editing the rest.

I thought of the following idea, the form searches for a row of data using an identifier number, then update the required row. The identifier will be an additional column to the sheet, the form looks for that cell and edit the required cells in that row.

Do you think this is a good idea or is there a better way doing it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It call Primary Key on SQL; but you are right.

Try to specify a column where you put the UNIQUE on that, then when input form shows up, read the whole table to search for row have that item, or you already select that cells, find the row index of it.
Reading data from cell to cell:

Cells( yourdatarow , i ).

After modifying on input form, you let user write back on to excel table.
Welcome you to the programming world.

Get familiar with VBA Excel, then moving to VSTO. VB.NET or C# is much faster when working with DATA on server. VBA is extremely slow on this.